# Blocking issue with Rx.NET Subject<T>

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, subject-observer

In a WPF application, I am using `Observable.Throttle()` to limit the frequency of handling certain events coming in from the user interface.

This is the minimal simplified code as it pertains to the usage of Rx:

```cs
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

public class UIEvent
{
    public UIEvent(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private ISubject<UIEvent> subject = new Subject<UIEvent>();

    // IEventAggregator is from Caliburn.Micro, but that should not be relevant here.
    public ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.subject
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .Subscribe(eventAggregator.Publish);
    }

    // This is called from several places in the associated view
    public RaiseUiEvent(string name)
    {
        this.subject.OnNext(new UIEvent(name));
    }
}
```

This generally works well and solves the race issue we had before. However, at some point, and even with a low frequency of events coming in, this will lock up in `subject.OnNext()`. Pausing in Visual Studio at that point shows the following relevant call stack:

```
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout)
[Native to Managed Transition]      Annotated Frame
[Managed to Native Transition]      Annotated Frame
System.Reactive.Linq.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Throttle<UIEVent>._.OnNext(UIEvent value)
ViewModel.RaiseUiEvent(string name)
```

I assume/hope the root cause is my very naive/inexperienced use of Rx. I tried synchronizing the subject, which I remember helped me with an issue in a different place, but that didn't change anything about the behavior here. I also experimented with `SubscribeOn()`/`ObserveOn()`, but with no real plan or luck.

Am I using the subject wrong? Should I be using a different subject type? Should I be using a subject at all? (Directly attaching to the events in the view via Rx and merging the streams does not seem feasible because of the complexity of the real-world code.)

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: What's the signature of eventAggregator.Publish?

Comment: Takes `object`, returns `void`. But I think that's the least important part of the whole thing.

Comment: Have you tried replacing  `eventAggregator.Publish` with a stub to see if the problem persists?

Comment: It is probably the Publish method that blocks. Hard to say without a repo though: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the `Publish()` method; that was the culprit after all. There is an asynchronous version of that, using which I cannot observe the issue anymore.